# How to display default parameters in the page URL in php?

Tags: php

I have created the php page named **sample.php**.I have used get method to get parameter values.

If no parameters passed from any pages get method uses default values.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
   $name = isset($_GET("name"))?$_GET("name"):"nithya";
   $id = isset($_GET("id"))?$_GET("id"):1;
}
```

Other pages in my project has the hyperlink to link to this page

`<a href="http:\\localhost\myproj\sample.php"></a>`.

I would like to display those default parameters in the URL even if no parameters passed from other pages.

```
http:\\localhost\myproj\sample.php?name="nithya"&id=1
```

Comment: what you have tried where is your code ?

Comment: if you dont have any parameter please redirect to a page setting default parameter using header() method. inside your header method enter your location with default parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_GET['name'])&&!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header('Location:http:\\localhost\myproj\sample.php?name="nithya"&id=1');
}
```

Something like this,
and inside your if condition check you parameter like

```
if(!isset($_GET['name'].........&&....){

header....
}
```

**In your case:**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
   $name = isset($_GET("name"))?$_GET("name"):"nithya";
   $id = isset($_GET("id"))?$_GET("id"):1;
   header('Location:http:\\localhost\myproj\sample.php?name="'.$name.'"&id='.$id);
}
```

You can not show these parameter directly on your URL, easiest way is to redirect the page having parameter. Another good way might be using `htaccess`

Comment: Have an upvote from me. It’s annoying when somebody downvotes with out an explanation.

Comment:  hehhee thats right, actually i did not want to answer for this post only i did comment and i thought comment will not be helpful if the user does not understand the comment only and then i answered.

Answer (score 1):

@Nithya try it like below:

```
 //Sample.html

    <form id="myForm" method="get" action="sample.php">

            Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Id:<input type="text" name="id"><br>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Send">

    </form>

    //Sample.php

    <?php
    if(!empty($_GET["Submit"])){
        if(empty($_GET["name"]) && empty($_GET["id"])){
            header('Location: http:\\localhost\myproj\sample.php?name="nithya"&id=1');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: have your tried ever, do you know what the use of empty() ?

Comment: oh yeah it works as same with little difference and now I saw, I did not use before. But whats wrong with my answer ?

Comment: you are answer also right but i did not down vote you, but why you down voted me ? only because some one voted you down and you think that i voted you down, that is not fare :(

Comment: that is nice @webDev (y) you got the new thing about empty() but you did not up vote me :p

Comment: @BunkerBoy Actually, I think you have an error in your logic. (a) The `&&` should be `||`, since you need both. (b) Your code executes `die` regardless, so the `header` is never executed. Shouldn’t it come after an `else`? Also, testing the submit button is easier if you just look for it in the `$_GET` array, such as `array_key_exists('Submit',$_GET)`, or more simpley `isset($_GET['Submit'])`.

Comment: asker said that If no parameters passed from any pages get method uses default values. that means both id and name must be empty that's why && operator has been used

Comment: (b) every time if i give answer to any one then i first try myself and that die was for me i removed that

Comment: @BunkerBoy see your comment and mine on original post. Thats all need to know by the user who posted the question nothing about logic nothing about isset or empty. only poster need to know header(), its not about giving working code, stack overflow is giving idea about how to solve too not only just code

Comment: and one more thing, sir please put `Location:` in your header() method.

Comment: @webDev  i was giving only an idea not a whole code